# Write function in terms of a combined variable

Tags: replacement

I am working with recursive convolutions of complex functions (fourier transforms), so, I calculate convolution integrals of functions of the form
$$g(iy) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(ix)f(i(y-x))dx, \ \  \to \ \  h(iy) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(ix)f(i(y-x))dx$$
So when I calculate these in mathematica (11.2), and I am a beginner user, I retrieve functions which are complex functions of $y$, while I want to have these as functions of $iy$. I could not find on the forum how to write these functions such that there are only $iy$ terms in the equation instead of $i$'s and $y$'s scattered all over the function...

Comment: If you introduce a new variable $z=iy$ and make the substitution `y->-I z` in the final result, does it solve your problem?

Comment: No, as there can be an $iy$ in the equation as well, which results in a $-y$

Comment: How come, $i\times (-i) =1$, isn't it?

Comment: In the resulting equation, there can be $\pm y$ and $\pm iy$ terms, therefore substitution of a single variable does not work. I'm sorry I guess that this is not clear from the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer myself:

if `g[y]` is the output function, then the following solves it:

```
Solve[{gs == g[y], s == (I y)}, gs, {y}]
```

where `gs` is the function $g(s)$ with $s=iy$ (think of the Laplace variable)

Comment: I don’t understand how exactly this solves the problem. Can you define the functions here in the original question for future users?

Comment: I changed the answer accordingly!